# Video processing in Android

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm using Android 2.2 with Eclipse.

I would like to make an application that captures video, and for each frame, its send it as a bitmap to a method that processes it *and returns a new bitmap* and shows the processed bitmap.

I am not very familiar with Android, so please, can anyone send me to the resources I need to look at to do such a thing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is simple enough to accomplish the following steps using the Android SDK:

- Capture the preview frames from the camera as bitmapped data.  `Camera.PreviewCallback` will return a `byte[]` of data representing the frame in a number of possible image formats.
- Modify the pixel data.  Since the data comes back as raw bytes, making adjustments to the data is relatively easy...the difficulty here is applying an algorithm for the particular image processing you want to do.  There aren't any built-in effects (pre-4.0) that can be applied simply to images so you will have to write your own.
- It is also possible to decode the data into a `Bitmap` object to make working with the pixels easier.  In 2.2, you have the option of using the NDK and jnigraphics to work with a Bitmap's pixels in native code, which is significantly faster than at the Java layer.
- Take the contents of your resultant `Bitmap` and display it.  For fast moving data, you would want to display this on a `SurfaceView`; using the `lockCanvas()` and `unlockCanvasAndPost()` methods available from the `SurfaceHolder` that view contains.

If this is all you are wanting to do, you could accomplish this with little difficulty.  However, this is not the same as capturing video.  Android does not currently provide hooks for you to stream frames out into an encoded video container (MPEG4, 3GP, etc.) in real-time.  It's video capture capabilities are wrapped up tightly into the `MediaRecorder` which controls the process from frame capture all the way to writing the encoded video.  You would need a 3rd part library such as FFMPEG (which has been built and run using the NDK layer a number of times in Android applications) to assist in the encoding process of your modified frames.

I know you have a 2.2 target, but Android 4.0 does provide some relief here as they have released a new version of the NDK which allows one to have more say in what happens when reading image data from a stream before handing it to the presentation layer.  However, I have not spent enough time with it to know whether it could be recommended for your situation.

Comment: I don't really want to catch a video, using the preview is great for me. Thanks!

Comment: hi, How can i create a video using series of bitmap images??? how can i render it?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do more complicated real-time video processing, I would highly recommend [OpenCV for Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html).

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is a computer vision library that enables you to process video in real-time, and it has libraries to perform simple tasks like detecting edges or more complicated tasks like detecting faces and matching features.

You can get OpenCV working in your Android cellphone in one day, especially because it includes extensive documentation and examples.

Comment: Does openCV is equally capable of, in terms of speed and ability, concatening image, processing codes and input streams, filtering etc just like FFMpeg.

Answer (score 5):

You can potentially use `Camera.setPreviewCallback` with `Camera.PreviewCallback#onPreviewFrame` to listen for preview frames coming from the camera.

Code for **2d Barcode** scanners might be a useful starting point:
[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android)