# processing video in android

Tags: android, video, rgb, video-processing

I am trying to figure out the right way to approach processing video (from file or camera) frame by frame on android.
I need to get each frame and convert it to RGB, process it (each color separately) and send it to the screen. 
Has anyone done it? how could it be done (preferably without any native code processing)?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620560/video-processing-in-android/15099170#15099170) where I suggest using [OpenCV for Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html). With OpenCV you can grab a video frame in RGB format and process each of the components individually in real-time.